# Unnest list and gather items with purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a list like:

```
list(list(goals = c(42L, 52L, 55L), 
          season = "88", 
          player = c("a", "b","c")), 
     list(goals = c(41L,53L, 37L, 40L), 
          season = "89", 
          player = c("a","b", "c", "d")))
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe in long format like:

```
goals player season 
42    a      88
52    b      88
.
.
41    a      89
53    b      89
.
```

I can achieve this using `plyr` like:
`plyr::ldply(mylist, data.frame, .id="season"`

I'm thinking there is probably an updated way of doing this using `purrr` or`dplyr`?

Comment: Can you give us the `dput(listname)` of your list? It's no fun to have to recreate data structures from scratch to answer a question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can do this by converting the `list` elements to `tibble` by looping through the `list` using `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
lst1 %>%
    map_df(as_tibble)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  goals player season
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1    42 a          88
#2    52 b          88
#3    55 c          88
#4    41 a          89
#5    53 b          89
#6    37 c          89
#7    48 d          89
```

---

A `base R` option would be to convert to a `list` of `data.frame`s and then `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, as.data.frame))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(list(goals = c(42, 52, 55), player = c("a", "b", "c"), season = 88), 
     list(goals = c(41, 53, 37, 48), player = c("a", "b", "c", 
     "d"), season = 89))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it using do.call, rbind and Map from base R with as_tibble from dplyr:

```
do.call(rbind,Map(as_tibble,lst1))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  goals season player
  <int> <chr>  <chr> 
1    42 88     a     
2    52 88     b     
3    55 88     c     
4    41 89     a     
5    53 89     b     
6    37 89     c     
7    40 89     d
```